# source code for funds transaction client-server module using Qt

Tags: database, qt, qt4

I want to develop a demo mobile application using Qt that does money transactions and shows account information to the user based on a demo database created and stored in the server program. Suppose you want to pay someone. Then you enter your password, account no. and then acc. no. of the receiver and the amount to be transferred to the receiver. The same change should be reflected in the database. If the amount to be transfered is less than the balance, or a bad password is entered an error message is displayed. The database should contain say five records with fields password, name, account no., and balance.

Please do help me out as I'm new to Qt and I have read books on it to accomplish the above program but finding it difficult to code.

Comment: @icktoofay I have a client server program for chatting.I just want to know how to add a database to it and do the transfer do send me some source code if u can .thanks for having a look.

Comment: "I want to make a site like Facebook, should take no more than 3-4 hours for a good coder. Stock equity. Contact me ASAP."

Comment: anybody there who can help me out please

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know how to do this I think you should use some easier technology like Java or c#, using hibernate or linq to persist to database. There are lots of tutorials on how to do this.